# Use gcloud with docker

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Trying to install gsutil into a container to do backups into google cloud storage.  When I install things manually into the container it works fine, but when try to automate it with a build I keep getting `bash: gcloud: command not found`  What am I doing wrong?

```
##Dockerfile##

FROM node:5

#RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update

RUN curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

RUN /bin/bash -c "exec -l $SHELL"

ADD ./ /src

RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

CMD ["/bin/bash"]


###docker-compose.yml##

backup:
  build: .
  volumes:
   - ./auth.json:/auth.json
  container_name: backups
  command: bash -c "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file     /auth.json"
```

Right now I'm running `docker-compose build`  & `docker-compose up` once that completes

Answer (score 0):

you forgot about the dot in the file path,
try with this command:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file     ./auth.json
```